# What is the gray zigzag line over V154 between Dublin VORTAC and LOTTS intersection?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, aeronautical-charts

Above Victor airway 154 on the IFR enroute low altitude chart, there is a grey zigzag line between [Dublin VORTAC and LOTTS intersection](https://skyvector.com/?ll=32.467442673819086,-82.26361084336237&chart=302&zoom=3&fpl=undefined).

What does the gray zigzag over the segment indicate?

[image: V154 between DBN and LOTTS]

<sup>**Credit: [SkyVector](https://skyvector.com/?ll=32.467442673819086,-82.26361084336237&chart=302&zoom=3&fpl=undefined)**</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [“Airspace Information” section](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/#ifr-airspace-information) of [FAA Aeronautical Chart User’s Guide](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/), it is a low-altitude unusable route. The high-altitude flavor is similar in shape with a smaller amplitude.

See also [page 62 of the Guide PDF](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/media/Chart_Users_Guide_12thEd.pdf#page=62), if you prefer.

> **UNUSABLE ROUTE** [image: Low- and high-altitude unusable routes]

In this particular case, observe the overprint on 110 in the compass rose surrounding DBN, which indicates abnormal status. The Airport/Facility Directory entry for Dublin VORTAC (as of the 31 MAR 2016 publication) reads, with added emphasis:

> **DUBLIN** N32°33.81′ W82°49.80′ NOTAM FILE MCN.
>     (L) VORTAC
>    113.1   DBN   Chan 78   276º 7.9 NM to W H 'Bud' Barron. 306/5W.
>   HIWAS.
>       VOR portion unusable:
>         215°–285° byd 10 NM blo 3,500’
>         **001°–139° byd 33 NM**
>         **001°–139° blo 5,000’**
>   RCO
>    122.1R 122.6 113.1T (MACON RADIO)

Note that the DBN 110 radial falls within the 001-139° unusable range. Beyond LOTTS intersection, V154 is defined with reference to the Savannah VORTAC.

Comment: What might make the route unusable? Why would it be marked out rather than removed?

Comment: Why does the route exist if its unusable?  What is it that makes it unusable?

Comment: My guess as to why it's still there is to make it obvious to someone who might be familiar with the area from the past that the route **did exist in the past** but now should not be used.

Comment: Is there a relation between the loss of reception and the two different radii of the VORTAC rose?

Comment: It would appear, [according to this](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://aeronav.faa.gov/acifp/2012070923317901001-V154/GA_V154_DUBLIN(DBN)-VORTAC-GA-TO-SAVANNAH(SAV)-VORTAC-GA_AMDTN.pdf&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjpgr7otOTMAhXDNSYKHWqFBE4QFggNMAE&sig2=hCYP-8m-8sesK8NeMZTTTw&usg=AFQjCNF-JLRK72uhAsmbw5oLnEPWjQPEEg) that they deleted that segment and raised the MEA for the LOTTS-SAV segment to 3000 ft due to towers built within the airway borders. Magic 98.1 has a tower 1.5 nm N of OCONE. And there's a cell tower 4.6nm NE of LOTTS

Comment: Okay, what about an aircraft with an IFR-approved GPS? Can that aircraft file & fly that portion of V-154?

Comment: @RalphJ: See the (new) linked question for this aspect.

Comment: @TomMcW: Why did the FAA allow the construction of towers that would obstruct air navigation?

Comment: @Sean I don't know. It was approved by the FAA in 2002 and built in 2004. The study that eliminated the route segment was not done until 2012. If you really want to know why they approved it in this specific case the FAA study that approved the tower is 02-ASO-1199-OE. I can't find that online anywhere. Not sure if they archived stuff online that far back.